# How to get async in jQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using the jQuery autocomplete plugin. The situation is that the hint data is taken via the GET API method. I can't make the code wait until the end of accepting data from the API.

```js
$('#vehicleBrand').autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $('#vehicleBrandValue').val('');
    $.get('api/brands', {
      query: request.term,
      category: $('select[name="vehicleType"]').val()
    }, function(data) {
      response(data)
    })
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $('#vehicleBrandValue').val(ui.item.data);
    event.target.classList.remove('border-danger');
    prepareModels(ui.item.data);
  },
  close: function(event, ui) {
    if (!$('#vehicleBrandValue').val()) {
      alertify.error('Error text here!');
      event.target.value = '';
      event.target.classList.add('border-danger');
      event.target.focus();
    }
  }
});
```

In the code above, on the `source` key, I call the get method to get the data.

```js
let brand = data.car_brand;
$('#vehicleBrand').data("ui-autocomplete").search(brand) 
$("#vehicleBrand").data("ui-autocomplete").menu.element[0].firstChild.click()
```

In the code above I am looking for a car brand and click on it through the script. But the click occurs before the request for data on the `source` key has time to complete, and the click occurs in the undefined list.
Where can I make the click wait for a response from the function by the key `source` ?

I tried to use Promise and `async`/`await` in function by key `source`, but it didn't work

Comment: Please take the time to format code in your questions properly. This was an unreadable mess before I edited it.

Comment: Your code is already using the async pattern correctly, due to the integration with the method that `autocomplete()` publicly exposes. The problem is most likely because you're trying to access `data` from somewhere which is out of scope of the `$.get()` callback. Where exactly are you executing the last 3 lines of code from?

Answer (score 0):

Might advise the following:

```
$('#vehicleBrand').autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response){
    $.getJSON('api/brands', {
      query: request.term,
      category: $('select[name="vehicleType"]').val()
    }, function(data){
      response(data);
    });
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $('#vehicleBrandValue').val(ui.item.value);
    $(this).removeClass('border-danger');
    prepareModels(ui.item.label);
  },
  close: function(event, ui) {
    if (!$('#vehicleBrandValue').val()) {
      alertify.error('Error text here!');
      $(this).val("").addClass('border-danger').focus();
    }
  }
});
```

Need to also make sure that you have `{ label, value }` pair someplace in your `data` results.

See more: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Using `$.getJSON()` is short hand for a AJAX GET Request that is expecting JSON data as a result.

If you are later using this code:

```
let brand = data.car_brand;
$('#vehicleBrand').data("ui-autocomplete").search(brand) 
$("#vehicleBrand").data("ui-autocomplete").menu.element[0].firstChild.click()
```

The code will execute right away, before results have loaded. You may need to delay the trigger using `setTimeout` since there is not a Promise to execute after. Something like this might work:

```
$('#vehicleBrand').autocomplete("search", data.car_brand);
setTimeout(function(){
  $("#vehicleBrand").autocomplete("widget").find(".ui-menu-item:eq(0)").trigger("click");
}, 1200);
```

This give Autocomplete time to load the events before triggering a click event.

Comment: Using getJSON didn't help, solved the problem. Still `$("#vehicleBrand").data("ui-autocomplete").menu.element[0].firstChild.click()` is processing before the response from getJSON comes. As soon as I give setTimeout to .click(), the script works as expected.

Comment: @MuhammetHudayberdyev where is the Click being triggered? Sounds like it is being executed elsewhere and not in the Autocomplete code.